# Clojure - how to cast DirectByteBuffer (returned by getChannel.map) into MappedByteBuffer?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I need Clojure to do a simple task for me, which is equivalent to the following Java code:

MappedByteBuffer out = new RandomAccessFile("file", "rw").getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 100);

However Clojure is a dynamic language, map() returns DirectByteBuffer instead of MappedByteBuffer. I wish to use setInt() method, which is a member of MappedByteBuffer. Is there a way to tell Clojure to use methods in MappedByteBuffer instead of DirectByteBuffer?

Thanks!

BTW this is my try:

```
(defprotocol MfileP
  (at     [this pos])
  (get-i  [this])
  (set-i  [this val])
  (resize [this size])
  (fsize  [this]))

(defrecord Mfile [fc buf] MfileP
  (at     [this pos]  (.position buf pos))
  (get-i  [this]      (.getInt buf))
  (set-i  [this val]  (.setInt buf val))
  (resize [this size] (assoc this :buf (.map fc FileChannel$MapMode/READ_WRITE 0 size)))
  (fsize  [this]      (.size fc)))

(defn open [path]
  (let [fc (.getChannel (new RandomAccessFile path "rw"))]
    (let [buf (.map fc FileChannel$MapMode/READ_WRITE 0 (.size fc))]
      (Mfile. fc buf))))
```

the form (set-i) throws an exception, because Clojure is looking for .setInt in DirectMapBuffer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say how you think you've established that `map()` is returning `DirectByteBuffer`. It isn't - It is returning a subclass of the abstract class `MappedByteBuffer` without doubt.

There is no method `MappedByteBuffer#setInt(int)` according to JDK docs.

You should code to the interface.

See:

[java.nio.FileChannel#map(...) javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29)

[java.nio.MappedByteBuffer javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a example for your reference.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(import [java.io File RandomAccessFile])

(def ^:private map-modes
  {:private    java.nio.channels.FileChannel$MapMode/PRIVATE
   :read-only  java.nio.channels.FileChannel$MapMode/READ_ONLY
   :read-write java.nio.channels.FileChannel$MapMode/READ_WRITE})

(def ^:private map-perms
  {:private    "r"
   :read-only  "r"
   :read-write "rw"})

;; read a Memory-Mapped File
(with-open [file (RandomAccessFile. (File. "./data/test.txt") (map-perms :read-only))]
  (let [fc (.getChannel file)
        buffer (.map fc (map-modes :read-only) 0 (.size fc))]
    (println (.isLoaded buffer)) ;; false
    (println (.capacity buffer)) ;; size of file 7087200
    (doseq [i (range 0 (.limit buffer))]
      (print (char (.get buffer))))
    (println "End of reading a Memory-Mapped File")))
```